# syntactic analysis under Split INFL Hypothesis

Tags: syntax, movement

I'm a beginner in linguistics, and so here is my problem under the early theory of Split INFL Hypothesis (Pollock, 1989; Belletti, 1990; Haegeman, 1994).

Here are the sentences.

a.They must have been spoiling the boy.

b.They can't have been spoiled the boy.

I have learned before that words like *must/can* are generated under the head of TP, while auxiliary verb *have/be* in English has its own VP, and of course, the verb *spoil* as well.

Now the problem is, I don't understand the movement. If auxiliaries *be* and *have* go under V-T movement with modal *must*, which further go to the Agr position, then how can *be* become *been* and *spoil* become *spoiling*? Or is there another way to move?

Great thanks.

Comment: The second one is ungrammatical. Passives have no direct object, and epistemic _can_ doesn't occur except in a negative context, like _They can't have spoiled the child/They can't have been spoiled by the child_.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks, I believe you are right. The second sentence should have a negative mark. I will change it into a negative. But the question still exists, since NegP is in a relatively higher position, and I still don't know the way -en combines with be and -ing combines with spoil.

Comment: Ask somebody who believes Pollock, Belletti, and Haegeman had a clue.

Comment: @jlawler "Passives have no direct object" <-- Well, usually. But ditransitive may: "I was given a book", for example.

Comment: True; but they're easy to spot and this isn't one of them. Plus, if you consider that a direct object, why not _The book was given me by a friend_?